# Missing off-topic flagging options

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flagging

When flagging a post for being off-topic, the following options are given:

- Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. A list of these references can be found here: List of general references
- Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: About single word requests
- Proofreading questions are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified.
- This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

What about the other cases that are mentioned in the FAQ On-topic/Off-topic List? The Off-topic List contains the following categories that it is not currently possible to flag for:

- Naming, including programming
- Literary criticism, discussion, and analysis
- Writing advice
- Translation/non-English languages
- Jokes that do not rely on the English language

Personally, I have not (in the six or so weeks I have been an active contributor) come across any questions that deal with the latter two; but the former two especially are quite frequent. I always want to flag these questions, but find that I cannot, except through the hack of “it needs ♦ moderator attention”, writing the actual reason in a comment box. This seems rather inferior to me.

Without knowing how the moderating system works, I would imagine that the whole point of having such a fine-grained flagging system is that it enables significant automatisation of moderation processes in the ‘already defined option’ cases, whereas the “it needs ♦ moderator attention” cases by definition require more attention and work.

So would it not make good sense to be able to flag questions as off-topic for all the reasons mentioned in the off-topic list, rather than just a (seemingly random?) extract of them?

Comment: When you get to actually close-vote, there is a wildcard Off Topic close option where you can fill in the missing reason. This keeps the dialogue box reasonably short, whereas adding those other five off-topic options would not.

Comment: At what point does one reach the stage of being able to actually close-vote? And does this mean that users who have not yet reached that stage are discouraged from flagging questions as off-topic if they are not within the options available in the dialogue box?

Comment: See [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/privileges) for an explanation of the various privileges.

Comment: There's no harm in flagging. If it's a valid flag it will add to your "helpful flag" count, even if the question is closed before a mod gets to your flag [At least, that's my experience]. All members of the community are encouraged to participate as much as their rep allows; and if that means you flag instead of directly vote to close, then do that.

Comment: I frequently flagged both Qs & As (100+) before I had enough rep to close vote - and all but 8 flags were "deemed helpful". I still flag answer sometimes, but for Q's I either propose closure or add my votes to an existing proposal, if I agree.